# Error - "Align used inside equation", and unexpected \end{equation} after \begin{document}

Tags: equations

I have an error in my overleaf document but it is still compilable. I am not sure why im getting the error because I simply use the align function inside the equation function.

[image: tion and]

Comment: Remove the `equation` environment. `align` already enters math mode. Alternatively, leave `equation` and replace `align` by `aligned`.

Comment: @campa thank you, replacing align by aligned was better as it does not give a new numbering to each equation line

Comment: also never leave a blank line before a display math equation and never have one equation following another. use `gather` to have unaligned equations following each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The environments `align`, `alignat`, `flalign` (and the corresponding starred variants) are top-level math environments and cannot be nested in other displayed equations (with a notable exception: you can use `align` & Co. within `gather`). Therefore you should either remove the "external" `equation` environment or use the "internal" form `aligned`, or `split`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\textwidth=5cm % just for the MWE

\begin{document}

\noindent\texttt{align}
\begin{align}
a &= b + c \\
  &= d + e
\end{align}
\texttt{align+nonumber}
\begin{align}
a &= b + c \nonumber \\
  &= d + e
\end{align}
\texttt{equation+split}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a &= b + c \\
  &= d + e
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\texttt{equation+aligned}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
a &= b + c \\
  &= d + e
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\texttt{equation+aligned[b]}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
a &= b + c \\
  &= d + e
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Equations (4) and (5) look the same, but the solution with `aligned` supports more alignment points. The cases (3) and (6) give the same output here but will in general differ in the vertical spacing between the formula and the surrounding text, since `align` never uses `\abovedisplayshortskip`. (For this reason I generally prefer `aligned` with the `b` option, though that might be debatable.)

Comment: I vote fast your excellent answer. IMO (3) and (6) looks the same:-). Much compliments.

Comment: @Sebastiano They look the same in this example because I used a very tight column. However, (6) will possibly use `\abovedisplayshortskip`, while (3) will never use it.